# How can I bring a Canvas to front?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I overlapped 5 Tk.Canvas objects and each will have different images. I want to bring each canvas to front of every other canvases to draw pictures in the most-front canvas.

```
class window_tk():
def __init__(self,main):
    self.main=main
    self.canvas_org = tk.Canvas(self.main, bg='white')
    self.canvas_layer1 = tk.Canvas(self.main, bg='red')
    self.canvas_layer2 = tk.Canvas(self.main, bg='green')
    self.canvas_layer3 = tk.Canvas(self.main, bg='blue')
    self.canvas_layer4 = tk.Canvas(self.main, bg='black')
    self.btn_load = tk.Button(self.main,text = "Load Image",command = self.load_ct)
    self.btn_layer1 = tk.Button(self.main,text = "Draw in L1",command = self.bring_1)
    self.btn_layer2 = tk.Button(self.main,text = "Draw in L2",command = self.bring_2)
    self.btn_layer3 = tk.Button(self.main,text = "Draw in L3",command = self.bring_3)
    self.btn_layer4 = tk.Button(self.main,text = "Draw in L4",command = self.bring_4)

def bring_1(self):
    self.canvas_layer1.place(x=50,y=00)

def bring_2(self):
    self.canvas_layer2.place(x=50, y=00)

def bring_3(self):
    self.canvas_layer3.place(x=50, y=00)

def bring_4(self):
    self.canvas_layer4.place(x=50, y=00)
```

I thought the canvas.place() function will bring the canvas front but it was not. Which function can I use ? Or should I unpack all other canvases ?

Comment: Since `Canvas` has override the `.tkraise()` function, you need to call TCL command directly: `self.canvas.tk.call('raise', self.canvas._w)`.

Comment: @acw1668 You are my savior Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Canvas` has override the `.tkraise()` function, you need to call TCL command directly:

```py
self.canvas.tk.call('raise', self.canvas._w)
```

or

```py
tk.Misc.lift(self.canvas)
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I amended my answer to refer to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the answer given by acw1668.  The `lift` function doesn't work for Canvas objects.  His answer is correct.

All tkinter objects, Canvas included, support the following method:

**w.lift(aboveThis=None)**
If the argument is None, the window containing w is moved to the top of the window stacking order. To move the window just above some Toplevel window w, pass w as an argument.

This gives you full control over which widget sits on top.

https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html

Now that I re-read that, I see that its language is slightly incorrect.  "w" is any tkinter widget, "above_this" is another tkinter widget.  The function places "w" above "above_this" in the stacking order.

Comment: `lift()` and `tkraise()` have been override by `Canvas` to lift/raise canvas item instead, so it does not apply to `Canvas` itself.

Comment: I don't disbelieve you, but where is that documented?

Comment: In tkinter [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3fee7776e6ed8ab023a0220da1daf3160fda868b/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2972).

Comment: I'll check it out.  I see that the New Mexico Tech docs say that Canvas.tag_raise and Canvas.tag_lower don't work on Canvas window items, but I assume that's referring to items placed in the Canvas with Canvas.create_window.  Is that what we're talking about?

Comment: OP wants to raise the `Canvas` object itself, not the items inside it.

Comment: Yes, I now see the comment in the tkinter source that you are talking about.  I've used '`lift` to raise other types of widget in the z-order, but it doesn't work for a Canvas.  Weird, but I guess there are historical reasons for it.  You are correct and so it seems that my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions -

```
canvas.tag_raise(canvas_layer4) -> For bringing to front

canvas.tag_lower(canvas_layer4) -> For pushing back
```

Comment: He has 5 separate Canvas objects on top of one another, not one Canvas with 5 items in it.